# Oracle - Self Join to update a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with columns request_num,Customer id,.... There are few records for which the customer id is not updated. So I want to get the Customer id for same request num's and update the records for which the Customer id is null/blank. Please let me know if the below will work in oracle

```
UPDATE CUST_VW
    SET A.CUST_ID=B.CUST_ID 
    WHERE A.REQUEST_NUM = B.REQUEST_NUM AND B.CUST_ID!= NULL;


Sample Data
request_num|Customer id
12         | ANBZ
12         |
12         | 
13         | 
13         | xyz
```

I want to update the  customer id for request num for which it's null from the other records with the same request num.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
UPDATE CUST_VW C
    SET CUST_ID = (SELECT MAX(C2.CUST_ID)
                   FROM CUST_VW C2
                   WHERE C.REQUEST_NUM = C2.REQUEST_NUM AND
                          C2.CUST_ID IS NOT NULL
                  )
    WHERE CUST_ID IS NULL ;
```

The `_VW` strongly suggests that you have a view, which may not be updatable.  You should really be updating the underlying tables and not the view.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.Will try the above said and revert back.